# How to run multiple MATLAB scripts from python in a loop?

Tags: python, matlab

I would like to run a list of MATLAB scripts from python, this list is dynamic and can change for each run.
This is my function:

```
def RunButtonFunc(self):
        eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
        list_of_matlab_tests = os.listdir(self.matlab_tests_dir)
        eng.addpath('.\MatlabTests')
        for key in self.DB:
            tst_name_without_suffix = self.DB[key][0:len(self.DB[key]) - 2]
            invert_op = getattr(eng, tst_name_without_suffix, None)
            if callable(invert_op):
                invert_op(nargout=0)
```

The problem is that if some MATLAB script name appears twice in the DB, I get this error:

```
The current MATLAB session is shared already.  To share a session with a different name, launch a new MATLAB session, and then specify the name when you share it.
```

Is there any workaround for this? Is there a way to check if the session is shared already?

Comment: I think this means you call `matlab.engine.start_matlab()` multiple times? You should call that only once.

Comment: Note that your variable `tst_name_without_suffix` is totally unrelated to `eng. tst_name_without_suffix`. I’m not sure what your code intends to do, but it likely doesn’t do what you think it does.

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes you are right. I uploaded the correct code now.